# How to remove apache default page

Tags: linux

I'm new to linux and I install apache on my server but I can't remove the default landing page, this is my URL test.projectorion.co.za. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Linux Distro? The default document root for Apache is `/var/www/` (before Ubuntu 14.04) or `/var/www/html/` (Ubuntu 14.04 and later)
Try to find a index.html file on this directories!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.